# JQuery export to excel is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc, excel

I am developing a page that exports a HTML table to excel using a JQuery plugin. (https://github.com/rainabba/jquery-table2excel).

For some reason when the button is clicked absolutely nothing happens. I have identified my table, and called my function so I have no idea why this code is not working.

View~ (condensed)

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <a onclick="return ResultsToTable()" class="btn btn-default">Export</a>
  </div>
  <div class=col-md-10></div>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"><script>

<script src="~/js/jquery.table2excel.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function ResultsToTable(){
            $("#resultsTable").table2excel({
                exclude: ".noExl",
                name: "Results"
            });
        };
 </script>

 <table id="resultsTable">
    //table stuff
  </table>
```

Comment: Please open the developer tools of your browser and go to the tab called console. Then click on the button and let us know, if you get any error.

Comment: May just be a typo there, but it says `<a onlick` instead of `onclick`.

Comment: Thanks for the typo correction, edited it. This time when I ran the function I get this error: $(...).table2excel is not a function. So I guess it is not recognizing the function. Wonder why?

Comment: I have the <script> tags referenced just like the website describes.

Answer (score 0):

Correct this: 
`<script src="~/js/jquery.table2excel.js"></script`>

It looks like you do not load the library properly.
I guess it should be:

```
<script src="/js/jquery.table2excel.js"></script>
```

But adapt it to the right structure of your folders

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken jquery.table2excel.js is not working properly ATM. I tried running the demo from the repo and it didn't work for me.

I experimented a bit and found a solution:

https://github.com/rainabba/jquery-table2excel/pull/13

Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dekkard/8f1w6zom/)
(note that used is the fixed version, see the script includes at the top of HTML)

Just for compliance, JS code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('#export-btn').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        ResultsToTable();
    });

    function ResultsToTable(){    
        $("#resultsTable").table2excel({
            exclude: ".noExl",
            name: "Results"
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Great answer, upvoted, but I still get this error in the javascript console "$(...).table2excel is not a function", really weird.

Comment: This error means that table2excel plugin is not loaded on your page. Did you try the fiddle I provided? Just compare your code to it, and pay attention how the scripts are included and used.

Comment: I did just as the fiddle described. Of course now I have a new error. It says "Refused to execute script from 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/unconditional/jquery-table2excel/master/src/jquery.table2excel.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled." Any ideas?

Comment: The problem is that github is serving raw files with a different Content-Type than the one expected by browsers for the scripts. I updated the URL in my fiddle, and it should work fine now.

Comment: Your code from the fiddle works perfectly. So I copied over all the new <script> ref's, and even copied your javascript file code over and just changed names. It STILL says "table2excel is not a function" in console view. Any other ideas? Been a tremendous help so far.

Comment: If you're putting together a single page, can you post it's complete source somewhere, like pastebin ?

Comment: I added the complete view page to a paste bin. I moved my <script> references to the area where I the problem is occurring. Good amount of code there. http://pastebin.com/AHt4Vvnq

Comment: Overall it looks good. Can you post the rendered page source (i.e. open it in a browser and copy its HTML code)?

Comment: You're including jQuery and Bootstrap multiple times. Try removing lines 336-340 (includes you copied from JSFiddle) and look through the code for other duplicate includes.

Comment: Hmmmm. Removed all duplicates and still flags the same error of not recognizing the function.

Comment: Well, I guess to help you further I'll have to see it live.

Comment: Dude! I am facing with the same problem. Did you find any solution. Please share!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code snippet to export Excel file.

checkout this https://jsfiddle.net/santoshgawande/2fcsq7o6/1/

It is working fine.

```js
var Results = [
  ["Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4"],
  ["Data", 50, 100, 500],
  ["Data", -100, 20, 100],
];

exportToCsv = function() {
  var CsvString = "";
  Results.forEach(function(RowItem, RowIndex) {
    RowItem.forEach(function(ColItem, ColIndex) {
      CsvString += ColItem + ',';
    });
    CsvString += "\r\n";
  });
  CsvString = "data:application/vnd.ms-excel," + encodeURIComponent(CsvString);
 var x = document.createElement("A");
 x.setAttribute("href", CsvString );
 x.setAttribute("download","Data.xlsx");
 document.body.appendChild(x);
 x.click();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="exportToCsv()">export to CSV</button>
```